# How To Detect Windows Notification From Chrome?

Tags: windows

I want to detect when I get a notification from Google Chrome, such as shown below, and be able to detect which site is pushing that, if possible. Language doesn't matter either.

[image: Notifications bar]

Comment: You can use a [notification listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener) to see all the notifications. You can then filter to the ones from Chrome and then study the text to figure out what site it's from.

Comment: @RaymondChen That's exactly what I needed. Thank you. I can't find the check mark to accept your answer, do you know why?